# AVAudioRecorderDelegate Interruptions methods doesn't get called

Tags: iphone, audio, record, interrupt, interrupt-handling

My AVAudioRecorderDelegate Interruptions methods doesn't get called.
I set the delegate.

What might be the issue here?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

Is the delegate added to the .h interface header?